# How to write rewrite condition for request_filename different then specified

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm facing a problem with `htaccess`, i want to write a condition that will prevent to serve specified file.

If the requested filename exists, simply serve it so i have this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]
```

but how can i achive that one specified file will not be served ? i have this path used for my controller action. so for example `example/do_something.php`
is the path to file `do_something.php` but also is the path to my controller action and i want my `htaccess` file to serve this action instead of this file but only this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried as [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) said in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29514153/2160958)

```
RewriteRule ^do_something\.php$ - [L,NC]
```

and it didnt worked for me but i managed to solve it by redirecting this files to my front controller:

```
RewriteRule ^example/(.+)\.php$ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
```

So in this case if someone enter the path `example/do_something.php` the file wont be served and the request goes by front controller

Full example:

```
# If the requested filename exists
# And my route path for controller action is the same
# Don't serve file serve action
RewriteRule ^example/(.+)\.php$ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]

# If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
# We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]

# Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^example/do_something\.php$ - [L,NC]
```

This will skip `do_something.php` from all rules below this rule.

Comment: so i just add this after the rewrite condition for all rules below that condition yes ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get that. What are you trying to do with this rule? Can you clarify with some examples. Also better you place full .htaccess in question

Comment: thx for help, but it didn't worked if you want to know how i manage to solve it check my answer

Comment: See updated rule in the answer, this should be your first rule.

Comment: ok, you added `example` to path so it's fits my example now, but still it doesn't work.